# What function should I use to read the 5th line of a large file?

Tags: php, file-io

What php function should I use to count the 5th line of a large file as the 5th line is the bandwidth?

Example of data:

```
103.239.234.105 -- [2007-04-01 00:42:21] "GET articles/learn_PHP_basics HTTP/1.0" 200 12729 "Mozilla/4.0"
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what the file looks like, and what you want to do with the result that you get? Are you trying to read an integer on the fifth line of the text file, or the bandwidth required to transmit whatever text is on that line across the wire?

Comment: Do you want to read the 5th line in the file, or *every* 5th line?  Give an (short) example of the file and what you want to read.

Comment: i want to count the bandwidth which is on every 5th line in a large file - example of data:103.239.234.105 -- [2007-04-01 00:42:21] "GET articles/learn_PHP_basics HTTP/1.0" 200 12729 "Mozilla/4.0"

Comment: Based on your repeat of this question, I think I've finally figured out what you are asking. You don't want the 5th line, you want the 5th column. Actually, you want the 6th column, since -- counts as one. You're not concerned with the bandwidth, but actually the file size of the payload. Am I correct?

Comment: Hello, Sorry i meant to 4th line well colunms of the file even. The 4th line is where the bandwidth is and would like to count the whole of the bandwidth of the file which contains 1000 lines. Does that make sense? look at the example 12729 i would like all of the bandwidth counted in the 1000 lines of my file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read *every 5th line*, you could use an [`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/splfileobject) to make life a little easier (than the `fopen/fgets/fclose` family of functions).

```
$f = new SplFileObject('myreallybigfile.txt');

// Read ahead so that if the last line in the file is a 5th line, we echo it.
$f->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD);

// Loop over every 5th line starting at line 5 (offset 4).
for ($f->rewind(), $f->seek(4); $f->valid(); $f->seek($f->key()+5)) {
    echo $f->current();
}
```

Comment: Spl file functions are the way to go.

Comment: i want to count the bandwidth which is on every 5th line in a large file - example of data:103.239.234.105 -- [2007-04-01 00:42:21] "GET articles/learn_PHP_basics HTTP/1.0" 200 12729 "Mozilla/4.0" –

Comment: Sky12, have a look around stackoverflow (and Google!) for parsing Apache's access_log lines. Options go from `explode()`-ing the line, to using a regular expression to extract what you need, to using one of many existing functions to get the information you want.  That's the easy part.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file into a handle:

```
$handle = fopen("someFilePath", "r");
```

Then read the first 5 lines, and only save the fifth:

```
$i = 0;
$fifthLine = null;
while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
    if $i++ >= 5) {
        $fifthLine = $buffer;
        break;
    }
}
fclose($handle);
if ($i < 5); // uh oh, there weren't 5 lines in the file!
//$fifthLine should contain the 5th line in the file
```

Note that this is streamed so it doesn't load the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

http://tekkie.flashbit.net/php/tail-functionality-in-php

```
<?php

// full path to text file
define("TEXT_FILE", "/home/www/default-error.log");
// number of lines to read from the end of file
define("LINES_COUNT", 10);


function read_file($file, $lines) {
    //global $fsize;
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $linecounter = $lines;
    $pos = -2;
    $beginning = false;
    $text = array();
    while ($linecounter > 0) {
        $t = " ";
        while ($t != "\n") {
            if(fseek($handle, $pos, SEEK_END) == -1) {
                $beginning = true; 
                break; 
            }
            $t = fgetc($handle);
            $pos --;
        }
        $linecounter --;
        if ($beginning) {
            rewind($handle);
        }
        $text[$lines-$linecounter-1] = fgets($handle);
        if ($beginning) break;
    }
    fclose ($handle);
    return array_reverse($text);
}

$fsize = round(filesize(TEXT_FILE)/1024/1024,2);

echo "<strong>".TEXT_FILE."</strong>\n\n";
echo "File size is {$fsize} megabytes\n\n";
echo "Last ".LINES_COUNT." lines of the file:\n\n";

$lines = read_file(TEXT_FILE, LINES_COUNT);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```

Comment: Please include more detail in the future. Answers that only include links tend to be less useful because websites move or content changes.